# Using extensions on Chromium with Puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, bots, puppeteer, chromium

I'm trying to automate a buying process but I need to have a specific extension active. The extension itself doesn't need to be automated.

Is there a way to activate that extension on Chromium dev mode?
Or is there a way to open my normal Chrome session with all my extensions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it through a Chromium > `8.0.0`. You can specify an `args` option through the [class: Puppeteer, `puppeteer.launch()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions).

| [Condition](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `--load-extension` | Comma-separated list of paths to extensions to load at startup. |

```
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    //...
    ignoreDefaultArgs: [
        //...
        "--disable-extensions",
    args: [
        //...
        `--load-extension=${PATH_TO_EXTENSION}`
    ],
});
```

Alternatively, you could run Chrome instead of Chromium.

`executablePath` is a `puppeteer.launch()` option that let you set a path to a browser executable to run instead of the bundled Chromium.

> | Option | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `executablePath` | `String` Path to a browser executable to run instead of the bundled Chromium. If executablePath is a relative path, then it is resolved relative to current working directory. **BEWARE: Puppeteer is only guaranteed to work with the bundled Chromium, use at your own risk.** |

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#puppeteerexecutablepath